# ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' when running react native in the browser

Tags: react-native, webpack, babeljs, package.json, react-native-web

Have been trying to get a react native app to also run the browser. After following the guide in the babel loader github repo I get stuck on this error here.

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\Nikulás Óskarsson\Desktop\newapp\app'

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost ./src
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\Nikulás Óskarsson\Desktop\newapp\app'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost ./src main[1]
```

My package.json

```json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll",
    "onesky:pull": "node onesky/pull.js",
    "onesky:push": "node onesky/push.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@brainly/onesky-utils": "~1.4.1",
    "@bugsnag/expo": "~6.6.1",
    "@bugsnag/js": "~6.5.2",
    "@bugsnag/plugin-react": "^6.0.0",
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "expo": "^39.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-localization": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.7.2",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.3.0",
    "i18next": "^15.0.9",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lodash.padstart": "^4.6.1",
    "mobx": "~5.15.7",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "mobx-state-tree": "~3.17.3",
    "moment": "~2.29.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "randomcolor": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-i18next": "9.0.10",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.212.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "~0.9.3",
    "react-native-modal": "~11.5.6",
    "react-native-pose": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-swipe-verify": "^0.1.5",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "react-native-web": "^0.14.10",
    "react-native-webview": "10.7.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.96.0",
    "jest-expo": "^39.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "reactotron-mst": "^3.1.3",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.15.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: [ 'babel-preset-expo' ],
        plugins: [ 'module:react-native-dotenv' ],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
    };
};
```

Not sure if it is relevant to the issue I am getting but after trying to run it in the web it simply opens my app directory in a new tab.

Comment: I think I need more information. Like what does your main look like?